# Subtitles mixing with text

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I've tried to separate my subtitles from plain text using *two* blank space.
The first part of my .Rmd document looks like this

---

```
---
title: 'Script de Limpieza: errores de digitalizacion y division de base madre'
author: "Leonardo Doig & Karen Lau"
date: "10/9/2020"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---


{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)


some random words should be here

#### First subtitle  

there are 2 blank spaces after the first subtitle


{r message=FALSE}
library(lubridate)

#### Second Subtitle   

plain text (after the second subtitle there are 2 blanks spaces too)
```

---

but the final output it's always like this:

> plain text
> **First subtitle**  there are 2 blank spaces after the first subtitle

```
library(lubridate)
```

> **Second Subtitle**  plain text (after the second subtitle there are 2 blanks spaces too)

---

It only happens when I *Knit* my .Rmd file to .pdf. When I *Knit* to .html all this mess with the subtitles and plain text seems to be okay.

Comment: Can you give a complete reproducible example? I don't have this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you add to your post above the minimal markdown required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I ran this locally, putting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)` inside the `r` chunk, as well as created a "random" `r` chunk, and could not reproduce your issue. Please put the code into one chunk in your post some one can cut / paste to reproduce. In its current state this is not a reproducible problem. When I run what I think you intend for your code, the **plain text** is put on its own line (which is what you want). I would edit your question to clarify what I mean, but the code  I am using does not reproduce the issue (which is why I am asking you to update the question).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because currently the issue is not reproducible. The code example should be in one code block that reproduces the issue; it is not in one code block, and when I put it together, it does not reproduce the issue for me

Comment: So I'm not sure why you can't reproduce the issue that I had (?) but this is my last try

Comment: Thanks for updating the question! This may be version or platform dependent. I was able to run it targeting pdf and did not reproduce the issue. What OS and R version are you using ? I tried it on Mac and can try on Linux as well. This could also be a `pandoc` version issue as well. I am using pandoc 1.19.2.1.

Comment: I just ran it on both Mac OS and Linux, targeting pdf and it worked fine for me. I am running from R Studio not the command line. For linux, I am using **pandoc 1.17.2** (3.6.0) and for Mac **pandoc 1.19.2.1** (R 3.5.2). How are you running this and what versions are you using ? You can run `sessionInfo()` to get your R version, but pandoc will require running `pandoc -v` (likely with the full path to `pandoc`).

Comment: Hi, I'm using this line ```pandoc.installed <- system('pandoc -v')==0``` to see if I have pandoc installed, and I don't have it. Is it necessary to have it so I don't have any more issues (?). Also I work with Windows 10 and my R version is **4.0.2 (2020-06-22)**.

Comment: Are you using R Studio ? `pandoc` may be installed in a location that isn't in your PATH, but R Studio may know where it is (that is the case on my system, as I believe it installed with R Studio). I am not positive, but I think `pandoc` is necessary for `knitting`. I don't have access to a Widows machine or I would try it.
For future reference, sometimes including things such as OS and R version can be useful for tracking down issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of this behavior is that this markdown:

```
# Level 1
Text 1
## Level 2
Text 2
### Level 3
Text 3
#### Level 4
Text 4
##### Level 5
```

is transformed into that LaTeX code:

```latex
\hypertarget{level-1}{%
\section{Level 1}\label{level-1}}

Text 1

\hypertarget{level-2}{%
\subsection{Level 2}\label{level-2}}

Text 2

\hypertarget{level-3}{%
\subsubsection{Level 3}\label{level-3}}

Text 3

\hypertarget{level-4}{%
\paragraph{Level 4}\label{level-4}}

Text 4

\hypertarget{level-5}{%
\subparagraph{Level 5}\label{level-5}}

Text 5
```

With the common LaTex hierarchy of section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-subparagraph.

So the Rmarkdown formatting of `####` is defined by the LaTeX formatting of `\paragraph{}`. And in the standard LaTeX styles, paragraph doesn't get a line break. It's a classic question, there are several workarounds (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/paragraph-style-how-to-force-line-break-paragraph-make-paragraph-a-he) or [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/new-line-after-paragraph)), Here I'll use [that one](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1383). For that solution, we need to include this code in the LaTeX header:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Let's just save that code by itself into a file, say `reformat_paragraph.tex`. Now in our Rmarkdown document, [in the header](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html) we can include a reference to that LaTeX file:

```
---
title: "My Rmarkdown document"
author: "me"
date: "9/19/2020"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: reformat_paragraph.tex
---
```

And that should work!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This may also solve the strange problem here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1896

Comment: Indeed, including the `reformat_paragraph.tex` above seems to solve that other inversion problem.