# fourth level title in R markdown appears after the code chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

Part of my rmarkdown contains the following:

````
#### Chapter X

```{r}
wilcox.test(blah)
```
````

but the title (#### Chapter X) appears after the code chunk in rmarkdown. I need it to be where I write it (as in before the code chunk).

These are my output settings:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    df_print: kable
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: true
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
```

How can I adjust that?

Comment: Could you please share some more code of your script, like output settings please?

Comment: @Quinten I added the output settings of markdown to the question. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best possible solution, but the same problem has been addressed here:

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1658

Simply using the command:

```
#### Title 4
\mbox{}
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This question: [Subtitles mixing with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965202/subtitles-mixing-with-text) answers your question. You should add this code in a separate file called `reformat_paragraph.text` and include that in your `in_header` of your header document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Code:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: reformat_paragraph.tex
    df_print: kable
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: true
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
---

#### Chapter X

```{r}
x <- c(0.80, 0.83, 1.89, 1.04, 1.45, 1.38, 1.91, 1.64, 0.73, 1.46)
y <- c(1.15, 0.88, 0.90, 0.74, 1.21)
wilcox.test(x, y, alternative = "g")
```
````

Output:

[image]